# The undefined / null data comes in the shipping field

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, shipping, undefined-variable

On the second step of the checkout, there is delivery data on the right, null data comes to the name of the type shipping.

[image]

I also use the module `Shipping Table Rates by Amasty 1.6.4`
After turning on the module, the data does not come null but undifined

[image]

for what reason can it be and where can I find the cause of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is that in the shipping method that you use, the Title field is not filled, if it is empty, such a result will appear.

If you use `Shipping Table Rates by Amasty 1.6.4` there is such a field, fill it in and the result will change.